# System Shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, lightdm, login-screen

After a recent update (not sure which/when) the login screen no longer has the cogwheel for shutdown. How do I restore it?

I have three systems, only one (Toshiba laptop) has this issue.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't have the shutdown option in both login and lock screen as well. I have suspend option in the lock screen though.

Answer (score 0):

This affects me too. Looks like a Bug has already been reported:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1605117